# Is there a word for somebody who cares for his/her child too much?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have just finished watching the 3rd season of [*Lie to Me*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1235099/).

I am wonder whether there is a word for somebody who cares for his/her son/daughter/child too much, like *Dr. Cal Lightman*?

Comment: Am I correct to assume this questions was not about [Münchausen syndrome by proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchausen_syndrome_by_proxy)?

Comment: @oosterwal Horrifying.... Lightman is not a bad guy....

Comment: Jiang:  I meant no offense.  I'm not familiar with Dr. Lightman and the phrase 'cares for his/her son/daughter/child too much' is all-to-often associated with Münchausen.

Comment: "Münchausen syndrome by proxy" would be the exact opposite of caring for a child. It's pretending to care for a child, while hurting the child and enjoying the resulting attention.

Comment: @gnasher, alternatively it could be not causing harm to the child but seeking attention from others for the slightest symptom the child may have. ie. by exaggerating it or by fabricating symptoms that don't even exist. this isn't necessarily harming the child.

Comment: Please see additional relevant answers at "[An excessively solicitous parent](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284823/an-excessively-solicitous-parent)."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An entertaining neologism for this is *helicopter mom* or *helicopter dad*.  (The implication is that the parent is "hovering" over their child at all times.)

Comment: +1: a fun playful phrase, that’s caught on remarkably widely.

Answer (score 21):

You could call such a parent *over-protective*. Sometimes such parents are called *intrusive* or *smothering* (in the sense that their habit of getting between a child and the real-life ups and downs of experience may stifle a child's emotional growth).

Comment: To tell the truth, I do not like your edit to my question.... because in the original question, it may get different versions of answers for sons and daughters....

Comment: OK. I'll roll it back for you, but you should be aware that you can roll it back yourself as well whenever you see an edit of your material that you disagree with.

Comment: You should also be aware that you need a preposition after "cares" in that sentence: "for" or "about" would be appropriate.

Comment: personally i would prefer an adverb in that phrase, so "overly protective" would be more appropriate. heavens, has the adverb literally died?

Answer (score 10):

> **Overbearing** ([*definition from Merriam-Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overbearing))
>   : often trying to control the behavior of other people in an annoying or unwanted way

Answer (score 5):

One classic phrase is a 'doting parent'.

Comment: Yes, I was going to add "doting" myself, with a caveat: It has two senses - 1. overly parental, and 2. fondly caring.