# An excessively solicitous parent

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word out there describing an overly caring parent? E.g. a mother who is constantly calling her daughter, asking where she is, etc.

Comment: I can recall a personal example where my uncle used to keep my cousin as an '_expensive showpiece_' with reference to antiques, pots kept in museums under the constant supervision of the authorities. :)

Comment: Although the answers posted here are  good, and (with the exception of two) different/unique than in the much older post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - it is a pity, the choice here is much wider.

Comment: @Josh61 People can post their new suggestions in the "original", I've done that myself a couple of times. There's even a silver badge if you get just five upvotes.

Comment: Another approach is to add a comment beneath the earlier question, pointing to the later duplicate question and answers. (I've just added one to the earlier question in this instance.) As long as the duplicate isn't removed from the system altogether, interested readers can follow the link to these other answers. I would hope, too, that a moderator who decided to remove the duplicate posting would consider transferring worthy answers to the earlier post before proceeding.

Comment: I have a feeling this question ìs going to be reopened,so I'm posting the link to the earlier/original question. It shouldn't be reopened because the two are ABSOLUTELY identical but... [Is there a word for somebody who cares for his/her child too much?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13317/is-there-a-word-for-somebody-who-cares-for-his-her-child-too-much)

Answer (score 20):

Not a single word, but let me offer **helicopter parent**:

> A parent who takes **an overprotective or excessive interest** in the life of their child or children

([Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/helicopter-parent))

> **helicopter parents:** parents who try too hard to protect their children and organize their lives, even when their children have left school

(Longman)

> a parent who is **unable to let go** of their adult child(ren) and continues to monitor them and intervene inappropriately in their lives

([Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/helicopter-parent))

The last two definitions state the kids are more or less grown. The first definition seems to be more loose. Personally, I've always encountered this in context of more or less independent kids.

Answer (score 8):

***Mollycoddle*** is the word mostly used in Britain. A child who has their comforts attended at every turn by their mothers (or fathers) are said to be *mollycoddled*

**Later edit for people who are not happy with a verb**.

The parents *mollycoddle*. The child is *mollycoddled*.

If you want an adjective to describe the parents' actions then it is mollycoddling. ***They are mollycoddling parents***.

Comment: **Mollycoddle** is used to refer to the child not the parent.

Comment: "Mollycoddle" is a verb - the act of being overly protective.  Parents mollycoddle.  "Mollycoddled" is an adjective applied to the child to whom this is done.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop The parents *mollycoddle*. The child is *mollycoddled*. If you want an adjective to describe the parents' actions then it is ***mollycoddling***. They are *mollycoddling* parents.

Comment: Or you could say they are ***mollycoddlers***.

Answer (score 4):

**smother**

Not based on the old school definition of the word but going by the urban dictionary

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Smother

> A mother or overbearing girlfriend that smothers their adult child/
>   boyfriend with too much love, affection, bossy demands and food.

Comment: Note that it is dangerous to rely on the Urban Dictionary because, while it can be a valuable resource for current slang, their database is deeply polluted with in-jokes, misspellings, and truly transient usage.

Comment: See for example https://www.entitymag.com/helicopter-moms-smother-mother/ for a more reputable usage cite.  "To Helicopter Moms: How Not to Be a Smother Mother"

Answer (score 4):

A ***[cosseting parent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cosseting)*** or a ***cosseter***:

> - treating  with excessive indulgence; "grandparents often pamper the children"; "Let's not mollycoddle our students!"

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 4):

One of the most braodly used term is an "[***Overprotective***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/overprotective) parent" as the adjective means:

> Having a tendency to protect someone, especially a child, excessively:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 2):

Mother-hen might be useful, though it doesn't have to mean a parent.

Oxford Dictionaries says:

Definition of mother hen in English:
noun
informal
A person who sees to the needs of others, especially in a fussy or interfering way:

Answer (score 0):

The word is needy.

It's a slang word. You'll find it in Urban Dictionary as "Requiring attention beyond what is normative."

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=needy

Comment: "Needy" is a normal regular word, not a slang word (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/needy) and it doesn't not refer to parents who are overly caring. It could refer to a child who is being cared for, but not to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***hovering parent*** (also ***hover-parent***) and [***hummingbird parent***](https://www.childrenandnature.org/2014/03/10/seven-actions-parents-can-take-to-increase-outdoor-safety/)

> *Are You a Hovering Parent?*
>   [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/mia-redrick/holicopter-moms_b_1304094.html) [**Ngram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hovering+parent%2Chovering+parents&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chovering%20parent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chovering%20parents%3B%2Cc0)
>
> **hover-parent**: a parent who hovers over their child at every step,
>   especially on the playground, to prevent any possible bad event from
>   occurring, specifically broken bone, interaction with less important
>   child, fall from any height, etc.
>
> *My toddler wanted to play with the other kids at the playground but the hover-parents stood in the way*. [Urban
>   Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hover-parent)

Answer (score -1):

None of these are single words, but these are generally used to refer that kind of parenting.

***Lawnmower Parenting*** or ***Bulldoze parenting***

Source: http://www.parents.com/parenting/better-parenting/what-is-helicopter-parenting/